# Is there a formal term for "snail mail"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Once "email"* entered the lexicon, we needed a term to differentiate it from what we can call regular, hand-delivered mail. One term in broad usage is "snail mail." But in a project I'm working on, we need a term that is more formal and businesslike.

As currently written, the copy reads: "Terrestrial mail."

I'm looking for a good term to replace "Terrestrial." Any ideas?

(*AP Stylebook has eliminated the hyphen.)

Comment: does terrestrial mail excludes air mail?

Comment: I feel "paper mail" is much better than "postal mail".  Paper mail rarely goes by "the post" these days.  It's either a courier service, or, you very likely mean some sort of intra-office thing.

Comment: is it possible you're looking for "written confirmation" or "in writing" ? (I realise it can be ambiguous with email!)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Postal mail is the usual term when one needs to be formal. "Terrestrial mail" is not in use and would likely cause at least some confusion.

Comment: This may be an acceptable term. I fully understand the remarks above, that "mail" in and of itself should be sufficient. However, we have two major operations - one involving email and one concerning snail mail, and it is necessary to sharply mark the difference. Any possibility of confusion needs to be eliminated. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @TheRaven: This should do it, then; no one would think of email when they read "postal mail" or snail mail when they read "email".  It would also be possible to describe them as "by post" and "by email" but that might introduce slight confusion for some Americans.

Comment: In Australia I've never heard *postal mail*. It does get 5 million Google hits for the whole world, but when restricting the search to just Australia gets only 150k hits, the first of which at least seems really strange to me: "Know how to manage your ***postal mail*** online like Mail 2 Email Redirection, ..."

Comment: @hippietrail: What terms are common in Australia when differentiating from email?

Comment: @Charles: I haven't been aware of any non-IT type people trying to differentiate yet and I'm not in Australia right now to keep an ear out, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

Simply "mail" by itself may be sufficient. If you need to specifically reference physical mail delivered by the Post Office then "Postal Mail" may be preferable.

Answer (score 8):

It may be the case that *postal mail* is a formal term; I don't know if it is or isn't, but clearly it suffers from redundancy and ambiguity, and is used less commonly than *regular mail*.

Alternatives such as *regular mail, physical mail, paper mail,* and *surface mail* all have been used, as shown by a [1995-2008 ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snail+mail%2Cpostal+mail%2Cregular+mail%2Csurface+mail%2Cair+mail%2Cpaper+mail%2Cphysical+mail&year_start=1995&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for "snail mail,postal mail,regular mail,surface mail,air mail,paper mail,physical mail":
[image]

Every one of the terms has problems:  *postal mail*, redundancy and ambiguity (does it mean threatening notes?); *regular mail*, ambiguity (does it mean email or paper mail?); *physical mail*, clumsy; *paper mail*, informal; *surface mail*, inexact (more paper mail goes by air nowadays).  *Physical mail* is the only one of these terms increasing in use at the moment, but still is least used.

Comment: I thought "surface mail" was a term _specifically invented_ in opposition to airmail, back when airmail was a new and exciting thing.

Comment: I don't know the etymology of "surface mail"; you might be right; in any case, I recall the term being used, rightly or wrongly, to distinguish snailmail and email when email was new.

Comment: if you add "mail" to that list it outshines the rest.

Comment: @Eric If you add x to any ngrams list like "a x,b x,c x", x will outshine the rest because it will include the numbers from all of them, plus any other x refs there are.  It is, however, of interest to add email to the list, and look at different date ranges; for example, usage of "air mail" dominates all the others from about 1925 to 1990.

Comment: In a world where email is sent much more often than postal mail, I'm sure there will be people, especially younger ones, that would assume that "regular mail" is "email"

Comment: "postal mail" might be redundant in the world where only "postal service" provides mailing service. But nowadays when Internet also provides mailing service, IMO it is no longer redundant.

Comment: why is paper mail informal?

Comment: "Physical mail" is good. It really is the opposite of "electronic mail" which, as most of us have forgotton, is the origin of the term "eMail" (note I've gone back to inserting the upper case 'M')

Comment: *Physical mail* is problematic, because the processes involved in transmitting e-mail **are** physical processes.

Answer (score 2):

The term I immediately thought of is **"postal service"**.

I've never heard it used to cover electronic mail and it scores higher in Google Ngrams than all the other terms, and it wasn't a newly invented term after the rise of e-mail. Also, it's perfectly formal.

[image: ngram]

One minor drawback is that it surely won't work as a drop-in replacement in all possible uses.

Answer (score 1):

Just mail for the same reason there's no such place as East Virginia.

Comment: Now I have a new name for my next Daughter!

Comment: @user179700: "snail mail" or "East Virginia"?

Comment: Snail Mail if it is a girl, Snail Male if a boy.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **traditional mail**, which nobody said. Anyway… I like *physical*, *postal*, or just plain old *‘mail’*.

Don't overthink it. Simplicity is a big part of writing good copy. Just be direct and consistent across the text. Your reader will understand. Creating artificial verbiage to "sound formal" (i.e. convey authority) usually has the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1):

**In Canada, we use the terms lettermail (or letter mail)**.

Which is technically, **Lettermail™**, a trademark owned by Canada Post

I've added a Google trends chart (Covers 30 days) and on average it is outperformed by **postal mail**, but does hold its own.
[image: 30 day trend (Canada)]

**Letter mail** split into two words is even more popular, but it's not clear if this includes results with both words separately, like in "how to *mail* a *letter*"
[image: 30 day trend (Canada)]

Comment: How frequently?  It's a term used by the USPS as well (two words), just not that common outside of the postal service.  Novel answer to this question.

Comment: Apparently frequently enough, if Google web search trends are any indicator

Answer (score 0):

For the exclusive purpose of distinguishing from email, you could probably use *conventional mail*. I am of course, aware that email is already quite the *conventional* mail today!

However, the common idea of that phrase is such that it still evokes images of postal, courier and other modes of physical delivery (you might have already considered *physical* as well), including surface, air and sea mail.

Comment: Or *old-fashioned* mail.

Answer (score 0):

One way of avoiding the ambiguity is to use the proper name of the country's postal service. If one is speaking of sending something from the UK, one can thus say that it will be sent 'by Royal Mail'; if it is to be sent from the US, one can say that it will be sent 'by the USPS'. These terms have the additional advantage of distinguishing such services from those provided by the companies such as DHL or UPS (although that may be a disadvantage, if one wants a term that encompasses all of them, and puts them in contrast to e-mail). They also, obviously, cannot be used in a context that is intended to cover sending things from a number of different countries.

Another way of avoiding the problem is to just use the term *mail* and then use the term *hardcopy* in the characterisation of what is sent. If one says 'We will send you a hardcopy of the document by mail', it will be perfectly clear that the mail that is referred to is not e-mail.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the answers were given by others, above. However, if you want to use a similarly silly word to "terrestrial," in relation to "mail," try tellurian, telluric, terrene, gaian, hyperchthonic (my coinage). Are you writing about mail on Earth as opposed to intergalactic, extraterrestrial mail?

Comment: You forgot *sublunar*!